# dotnet test - possibility to override .net core configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, .net-core

Can the configuration values in an .net core application be overriden when executing tests through "dotnet test" (for example using AddCommandLine extension like you would use it when doing "dotnet run".

More info:

Tests do some integration testing through which Startup.cs is also executed from the asp.net core project, and I would like to override a configuration value there.

Comment: One option is to create a `Startup.cs` for tests, or, have a app.settings with your test configuration.

Comment: Have that already, looking for a way to override a configuration from that appsettings file

Comment: I have an appsettings.json (production) and an appsettings.development.json. You could do the same or create a new one: appsettings.test.json, for example.

Comment: I understand that you can have multiple config files (called transformations), but my question was whether you can override a configuration value from the command line, not by having a different configuration file!

Answer (score 0):

You should create an interface and a wrapper class to deal with the appsettings and either mock your interface or use fakes for your test project. then you will be able to control what you need to set as appsettings while testing